# OpenGL and SDL, resizing window while keeping internal resolution unaltered?

Tags: opengl, sdl

I am doing a game in OpenGL and using SDL for managing the window, setting the icons, and all that stuff.
Now that I have set rendering the scene to a framebuffer, I wondered if I could resize the SDL window while keeping my starting GL settings (I am trying to emulate a exact resolution so window resizing is a rescale of the framebuffer to the window size)

I tried giving the SDL window double the resolution of the resolution I pass to glortho, but it gives unexpected results©. Is this possible at all, or do I need to adapt my working resolution to the screen resolution all the time?
I use this code to initialize video

```
SDL_SetVideoMode(XRES, YRES, bpp, SDL_OPENGL | SDL_HWPALETTE);
gl_init(XRES,YRES);
```

And into gl_init I set glortho to glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1), and then the framebuffer "blank" texture to width and height in size, as well.

When the function is called as above, all is well. But if I try something like

```
SDL_SetVideoMode(XRES*2, YRES*2, bpp, SDL_OPENGL | SDL_HWPALETTE);
gl_init(XRES,YRES);
```

Instead of getting my expected results (scaled output) I find out that the output is somewhere at the far left on X axis and somewhere in the middle of the Y axis, like if GL size was even bigger than the screen and the rest was cropped out. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try to simply set the FBO texture size to 1/4 of the window size (1/2 of its edge lengths), then render the FBO's color buffer texture to the entire SDL window.

Comment: I would like to keep my GL "working" resolution at a fixed size...so that if the window is resized I'll keep working with the same number of pixels internally, and specially avoiding non-integer values, I had issues in an older project because of rounding errors from divisions destroying single-pixel details.

Comment: @Patrick: Then just make an FBO of the resolution you want. Then just draw it to the actual SDL window.

Comment: Patrick, your "working" resolution will be the FBO's resolution. That should work exactly the way you want.

Comment: Strange, that's what I tried and I got what I explained above, note that I already have the FBO all set and I keep it the same size, same with glOrtho, but just changing the SDL window size makes the output weird (it's like zoomed in at the left-center).

Comment: I didn't say you should make the OpenGL resolution different from the SDL window resolution. Just use a texture for the FBO that has the desired size (i.e. if SDL has 800x600, use 400x300 for the FBO texture).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it is a top result on Google and does not have an answer.

You'll need to call `glViewport()`. Suppose you want your internal resolution as 1024x768, and your window resolution is windowWidth and windowHeight. Before you write to your FBO, call `glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 768)`. Then, before writing your FBO to the window, call `glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight)`.

Answer (score 0):

You use this code in your game loop

```
int w, h;
SDL_GetWindowSize(Window, &w, &h);
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
```